# cherryPy global configuration - costume 404 error -

Tags: python, configuration, global, cherrypy

I have problems trying to configure a global 404 error in my cherryPy server.

This is my code.

```
import cherrypy
import os,os.path

import view.costume_functions as cf
import model.database as db
import temp.template as tm

class Maple_syrup_project(object):

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):

        query = db.get_racks()
        estado = {}

        for rack in query:
            ip_address = rack[1]
            key = rack[0]
            estado[key] = cf.estado_actal(ip_address)

        return tm.rack_all(query,estado)

    @cherrypy.expose
    def configurar(self,**post):
        comando = cf.comando(post)
        rack_id = post['rack_id']
        ip_address = db.get_ip(rack_id);
        respuesta = cf.connection(ip_address,comando)
        return comando
        return 'configurando...'+comando+'....'+respuesta

def error_page_404(status, message, traceback, version):
        return ('Oppps Error')

cherrypy.root = Maple_syrup_project()

if __name__=='__main__':
    configurations = {
        '/':{
            'tools.staticdir.root':os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
        },
        '/static':{
            'tools.staticdir.on':True,
            'tools.staticdir.dir':'./static'
        }
    }

    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_port':9999,
                            'server.socket_host':'0.0.0.0',
                            'error_page.404': error_page_404,
                            })

    cherrypy.tree.mount(Maple_syrup_project(),
                        '/control_de_retornos',
                         configurations)

    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

If I point my browser to ht..://....:9999/control_de_retornos/xxxxx
I got the expected costume error 'Ooops Error'.
if I point my browser to ht..://....:9999/ or to ht..://....:9999/xxxxx
I got a blank page with a Status Code:404 Not Found in the headers but it not my costume error.

Any ideas of what is going on?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
import cherrypy
import os,os.path

class Maple_syrup_project(object):

    class control_de_retornos(object):
        @cherrypy.expose
        def index(self):

            return 'hi'

        @cherrypy.expose
        def configurar(self,**post):
            return 'configurando...'

def error_page_404(status, message, traceback, version):
        return ('Oppps Custom Error')

cherrypy.root = Maple_syrup_project()

if __name__=='__main__':
    configurations = {
        '/':{
            'tools.staticdir.root':os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()),
            'server.socket_port':9999,
            'server.socket_host':'0.0.0.0',
            'error_page.404': error_page_404,
        },
        '/static':{
            'tools.staticdir.on':True,
            'tools.staticdir.dir':'./static'
        }
    }

    cherrypy.tree.mount(Maple_syrup_project(),
                        '/',
                         configurations)

    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

error_page_404 needs to be apart of Maple_syrup_project and not part of "class control_de_retornos(object):".  now when i go to the root of your path I get "Oppps Custom Error".
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It did not work.
I believe it did not work because configurations{} it is for configure my app and not the global server.

Comment: are you behind a web server?

Comment: well just the cherrypy server that launch when I run my file

Comment: ok - I think I see what's going on.  You're mounting your app to /control_de_retornos which means cherrypy won't handle anything without ht..://....:9999//control_de_retornosXXXX in the path.  So either mount to / or if you need control_de_retornos in your path make it another class in your py file.

Comment: I thougth solving the problem as you said. By making another class that mounts on " / " and returns the 404 error, but that solves only half the problem, because if I put point my path to http......:9999/xxxxxxx the response will be the same black page.
Thank you for the help

Comment: I updated my answer.  Also, are you getting an error about starting on 0.0.0.0?  My cherrypy errored and instead started on : http://127.0.0.1:8080/

Comment: let me check your update!! , I don't get an error staring my server at 0.0.0.0
staring the server at that ip allow others on my local network to see the webpage.

Comment: I tried your last answer, but it did work because I was not able to start the server on 0.0.0.0 ip.
I solved it as you said first. I made another class that mounts at / and handles the costume error.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Andrew Kloos

I solved it adding another class that mounts on '/' and handles the error

```
import cherrypy
import os,os.path

import view.costume_functions as cf
import model.database as db
import temp.template as tm

class Maple_syrup_project(object):

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        racks = db.get_racks()
        rack_collection = {}
        bson = {}

        for rack in racks:
            ip_address = rack[1]
            try:
                estado = cf.estado_actal(ip_address)
            except:
                return ('Opsss..... Error....... Verificar que los racks esten encendidos y bien conectados ala red')

            nombre = db.get_optos_name(ip_address)
            opto_collection = cf.create_bson(estado,nombre,rack)
            rack_collection['rack_'+str(rack[0])] = opto_collection

        bson['racks'] = rack_collection

        return tm.rack_all(bson)

    @cherrypy.expose
    def configurar(self,**post):
        comando = cf.comando(post)
        rack_id = post['rack_id']
        ip_address = db.get_ip(rack_id);
        respuesta = cf.connection(ip_address,comando)

        return 'configurando...'+comando+'....'+respuesta

class Index(object):
    pass

def error_page_404(status, message, traceback, version):
    return ('Oppps Error')


if __name__=='__main__':
    configurations = {
        '/':{
            'tools.staticdir.root':os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
        },
        '/static':{
            'tools.staticdir.on':True,
            'tools.staticdir.dir':'./static'
        }
    }

    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_port':9998,
                            'server.socket_host':'0.0.0.0',
                            'error_page.404': error_page_404
                            })

cherrypy.tree.mount(Maple_syrup_project(),'/control_de_retornos',configurations)
cherrypy.tree.mount(Index(),'/',configurations)

cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```